# I can only initialize the first struct variable in an array of structs.(Array length is 2)

Tags: c++

I use `new` to create an array of structs but I can only initialize the first struct variable.

When I assigned a value to the second struct variable, statements like `cin >> tbType[i].variableName`were not executed. This is my code:

```
typedef struct tbStruct
{
    string variableName;
    string TypeName;
    int len;
    int precise;
    bool IsNotNull;
    bool IsKey;
    tbStruct() : variableName(""), TypeName(""), len(0), precise(0), IsNotNull(false), IsKey(false) {}
} * structPro;

int main()
{
    structPro tbType;
    tbType = new struct tbStruct[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> tbType[i].variableName;
        cin >> tbType[i].TypeName;
        cin >> tbType[i].len;
        cin >> tbType[i].precise;
        cin >> tbType[i].IsNotNull;
        cin >> tbType[i].IsKey;
    }
    delete[] tbType;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enter"?

Comment: sorry, I mean to assign a value to the variable

Comment: Try not using the word struct after new, as you already made it a typedefinition and don't need the word struct every time you make a new instance of it

Comment: thx~, but I still can't assign to the second variable, the statements like `cin>>tbType[i].variableName` were not executed

Comment: Your code works flawlessly on my machine. How are you running your code? What inputs are you passing?

Comment: Did you put spaces in `variableName`?

Comment: That is the problem. Once you put a space then you will go to the next variable. If you want to have spaces then use getline instead of cin.

Comment: sorry for the confusion~, the input I pass is `score varchar 10 2 false false`, when I tried to input a second time, the program quit

Comment: thx, I fix it, I did want to assign values to the following variables, but I inputed `false` to a variable of type bool  in cmd window which should be 1 or 0, many thx! @bhristov

Comment: No problem. I am happy that you fixed it!